# Diana Stanley dreams of a sunken city

Tags: arkham-horror

Does Diana Stanley gain sanity from doom tokens when the environment "Dream of a Sunken City" is in play?

Diana Stanley's unique ability:

> Dark Insight - Any Phase: Gain 1 Sanity or 1 Stamina each time a doom token is added to the Ancient One's doom track

Dreams of a Sunken City Mythos card:

> Mythos Ability: Investigators cannot gain Sanity except by receiving psychiatric care at Arkham Asylum (or from Carolyn Fern).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Diana Stanley's Dark Insight ability does not override the effects of the Mythos environment in play. If it would override the Mythos card, it would state so.

For example, Akachi's ability states:

> Secret Rites - Any Phase: Akachi gains +1 bonus to all skill checks to close or seal a gate. In addition, Akachi may always seal gates, regardless of other game effects.

Answer (score 5):

No. The mythos card says "investigators cannot gain sanity" with a couple exceptions, and her ability says "gain sanity" and is not one of the exceptions. She can of course still gain stamina, though.